# Технология или модель управления ролями и правами доступа

Tags: c#, база-данных, проектирование, права

Посоветуйте пожалуйста модель управления ролями и правами доступа пользователей, как лучше (и вообще как это делается) хранить в базе данных (например Oracle или MySQL). Как вообще происходит взаимосвязь с этой системой. Разрабатываемая система - многопользовательское desktop приложение на C#

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас desktop-приложение, то самое правильное что вы можете сделать - это хранить все данные в профиле текущего пользователя.

Для хранения настроек можете использовать стандартный мастер из студии (свойства проекта - Settings/Настройки) в пространстве (Scope) Use (значение по умолчанию).

Если вам нужна СУБД - то можно использовать файловую, например SQLite.

Если вам нужна мощная серверная СУБД - то неплохим вариантом будет Microsoft SQL Server в режиме интегрированной безопасности (она же Windows авторизация). Напомню, что редакция Express бесплатна.

---

Если же вам нужна авторизация в сторонних программах, (в том же Oracle) - то пароль надо хранить где-нибудь в конфиге, который лежит в профиле пользователя.

Кстати, если на этот конфиг повесить атрибут "зашифровано" - то даже администратор не сможет его прочитать.

Также можно добавить шифрование своим ключом - чтобы пароли нельзя было прочитать из других программ.

Answer (score 0):

Не однократно видел в Enterprise-решениях схему (умолчу о названии продуктов), когда параметры ConnectionString жестко захардкожены (hardcoded) и скрыты от пользователя вообще, и соединение с БД всегда происходит под одним пользователем. Тем не менее, пользователь вводит для авторизации пару логин/пароль, но эти данные используются не для подключения к СУБД, а для реализации логики прав доступа на уровне самой базы данных и средствами этой базы данных. 
Т.е. вся логика прав реализуется самим приложением и серверными скриптами, без привлечения механизмов распределения доступа самой СУБД.

Хорошо это или плохо - другой вопрос, но такая реализация системы прав доступа имеет место быть.

Comment: Примерно такая логика в первую очередь пришла в голову. По архитектуре она вполне устраивает.А разрешения для того или иного пользователя в битовых масках хранить?

Comment: А второй тип реализации, я так понял, организовывается средствами СУБД?

Comment: В тех продуктах, что я видел - права хранились в таблицах БД. Само подключение к базе данных осуществляется под пользователем DB_User, который имеет доступ к сущностям БД. Этого логина ваш пользователь не видит/не знает, а вводит он логин User1, и далее смотрим в таблице БД какие права и на что (на какие сущности) есть у пользователя с логином User1.

Как именно реализовать права (т.е. какие поля в таблице должны быть) - это уже по ситуации. Если подходит битовая маска, то можно и её. Но обычно всё сложнее - смотрят, входит ли пользователь в какую-то роль, и применяют права для этой роли.

Comment: В качестве иллюстрации предлагаю вниманию такую статью: https://habrahabr.ru/post/51327/ Не обязательно делать так же, но общее понимание концепции она, надеюсь, поможет получить.

Comment: Еще статья для иллюстрации примера: http://tmaplatform.ru/page/help/spec/2grants

Comment: @BlackWitcher статья, на которую вы ссылаетесь, говорит про ***веб***-приложение. Не десктопное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я знаю. Потому и оговорился что совсем не обязательно делать так же (копи-пастом, да и не получится, ибо php). Основная суть этой статьи - организация системы прав в базе данных. **Абсолютно ничто не мешает применять такой подход для десктопных приложений**. До кучи - привел *для иллюстрации* еще одну статью выше.

Comment: @BlackWitcher очень мешает тот факт, что такая система прав защищает только от неквалифицированного пользователя. Любой специалист сможет зайти напрямую в базу и назначить себе максимальные права.

Comment: Так уж и любой? )
Цитирую из ответа: *Хорошо это или плохо - другой вопрос, но такая реализация системы прав доступа имеет место быть.*

Это раз. Второй момент - всё зависит от конкретной технической реализации. Существует далеко не одно коммерческое решение в Enterprise практике в связке "толстый клиент - MS SQL" где коннект к  БД идет вообще чуть ли не под sa, а дальше права уже рулятся на основании собственного механизма, не имеющего отношения к движку БД и его реализации ACL.